# If you roll 6-dice three times, what is the chance of getting 4 only once?

Tags: probability

> If you roll dice three times, what is the chance of getting $4$ exactly once?

I know the answer $\frac{25}{72}$ (given by a friend of mine). However I tried to work to the answer out and I have failed many times.

I tried counting the chance of getting the $4$ on first roll is $\frac{1}{6}$. Thus I know the probability must be higher than $16.6%$ . 
If I would get two rolls of $4$, the chance of that is $\frac{1}{36}$ or $2.77%$.

Now here is where I get lost (haven't done any probability for $6$ years) How do I count the chance of getting a four on second try, and if unsuccessful on first, how do I count chance of getting a  four on third try, if unsuccessful on first and second. How do I even count the chance on the third try, should be chances outta $216$?

Should I have drawn out a pyramid, I mean I could but its not the simplest way of counting it.

Comment: hint: you can get 4 on first attempt only or second attempt only or 3rd attempt only. What is the probability of getting a 4 on first attempt?

Comment: Welcome to stackexhange. Although you did get an answer you have lots of downvotes. That's because you did not show any effort of your own. When you ask a question here you should include what you tried, and where you got stuck. If you do that you are more likely to get an answer using ideas you will understand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we pick two dice which are not $4$.  There are ${3\choose2}$ ways to do this, and that they are both not $4$ occurs with probability $\frac{5}{6}^2$ since the dice rolls are independent events.  That the remaining roll is $4$ occurs with probability $\frac{1}{6}$.  Thus the total probability is given by multiplying...

$${3\choose2} \left(\frac{5}{6}\right)^2\frac{1}{6} $$

Comment: And how did you get this answer?

Comment: By studying my probability class instead of relying on other people to have my exercises done.

Comment: Actually ... its double that. Is it the (3 2) [no idea how to write that] ways?

Comment: It is called binomial coefficient. It stays for ${n\choose{k}}=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$. It gives you the number of ways you can pick $k$ objects from a set of $n$. In this case ${3\choose{2}}=\frac{3!}{2!1!} = 3$. You can write it as {n\choose{k}} inside a math environment.

Comment: Ah I get it now. Thanks D: hm... is this the easiest way to do it? Were you not to have calculator and four options 25/72 and 29/72, how would you pick the right one fast enough? (usual time for each question is around 45 seconds)

Answer (score 0):

If we throw a dice 3 times total number of unique results or phases are 6×6×6
And among all results to wet get 4 at any one dice is 3C2×5^2
So the probability is 3×5^2/6^3=(25/72)